# How do I http.ListenAndServe "/" and not have it respond to every path?

Tags: http, go, server

I have the following code in a small golang server:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {})
```

Basically allowing you to hit the root of the server without anything scary happening.

The issue is that you can also hit `/foo/bar/blah...` and it still works. Which I don't want.

How can I explicitly restrict it to what I say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code to the beginning of your handler:

```
if r.URL.Path != "/" {
     http.NotFound(w, r)
     return
}
```